# Why won't this rewrite rule work?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Here's the setup.

I have a custom post type 'Businesses'.
I have a custom taxonomy 'Display Category'.
And I have a second custom taxonomy 'Filters'

Both taxonomies are set to work with the custom post type.

I am trying to get a url structure that looks like this

www.domain.com/businesses/display category term/filter term

There are only 3 possible choices for the Display Category, those are eat,stay, and play. The Filters then have quite a few choices. so here is the rewrite rule I have so far but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

```
function test_add_rewrite_rules() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(
        'businesses/(eat|stay|play)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=businesses&display_category=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&filters=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2),
        'businesses/(eat|stay|play)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=businesses&display_category=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)

    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'test_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

I am using a rewrite rule inspector plugin so I know the rules are being added. But they are not returning the pages I want. I found this article about [rewrite rules](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/) and it helped me get this far but I am stuck now. Any help would be greatly apprecieated!

### Update

Here is the above code but instead using the add_rewrite_rule function. I have hooked in into init for now because the generate_rewrite_rules hook was firing too late for the new rules to be save. I also realized that I will need to get the paged rules to work as well but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
function test_add_rewrite_rules() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_rule('businesses/(eat|stay|play)/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=businesses&display_category=$matches[1]&filters=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('businesses/(eat|stay|play)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=businesses&display_category=$matches[1]', 'top');

}

add_action( 'init', 'test_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: Only a technical note, it's preferable to use `add_rewrite_rule()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. I will switch over to using that function. Any idea what hook I should use to run it?

Comment: `init` should be sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your rewrite rules account for the `paged` parameter, because otherwise they won't. It would look somewhat like shown below.

```
function test_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'businesses/(eat|stay|play)/(.+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=businesses&display_category=$matches[1]&filters=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'businesses/(eat|stay|play)/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=businesses&display_category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'test_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I also figured out that I have to order the rules in a specific way. I had to put the paged rules above the regular rules for them to tested first. Which is a bit counter intuitive when you also use the 'top' argument with add_rewrite_rules(). But I got it working in the end!

Comment: My pleasure! True, its a bit counter intuitive, but there is no priority or something else, so you have to order them somehow. Besides `top` only does mean they are checked before WordPress' rules. @yoxalld